# Android: Is it possible to make a Contentview dynamic?

Tags: android, class, variables, layout

Is it possible to create just one class and use a variable for contentview?  I am thinking of creating a main layout with loads of buttons with IDs.  Once a button is pressed it'll then pass the ID to the class and use that ID to open a specific Layout.  One class, multiple layouts.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); //is it possible to make 'main' a variable?
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

`R.layout.main` resolves to an integer (or maybe a long, I forget) so you should be able to set up some kind of control structure like so:

```
switch (mSomeDeterminingFactor) {
    case 1:
        layoutChoice = R.layout.main
        break;
    case 2:
        layoutChoice = R.layout.altMain1
        break;
    case 3:
        layoutChoice = R.layout.altMain2
        break;
    case else:
        layoutChoice = R.layout.main
        break;
 }
 setContentView(layoutChoice);
```

Edit: You should be careful how you use/save/store this number later though as you cannot guarantee the resource values will be the same. You should continue to reference them via the R class.